# What is this cream-yellow flower?

Tags: identification, flowers

What is this cream-yellow flower?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

New photos:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Where is the flower located?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's a Oenothera; possibly O. biennis or, if the OP is North America, O. pilosella. The elongated flower buds are good clue, plus what we can see of the flower, but the leaves are somewhat off for both species (closest to O. pilosella). A picture showing the entire plant from farther back would be nice to help confirm.

Comment: I added some photos. There are twp plamts of that lind, growing very closely

Comment: But it is a crowded area, they are squeezed.

Comment: It does show flowers in full only at night.